# How to modify this regex so it doesn't match the space before opening square bracket?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex to match the title of situations written in Chinese and English (second capture group):

```
(^.*[ ]\(\d{4}\)\.[ ])([^[.]+)(.*)
```

Example of citations:

> 方圓媛, 洪佳黛, 詹瑞君, & 李芸湘. (2017). 談癌症病人家屬照顧者心理衝擊與介入方案 [Psychological
> Impact of Nursing Interventions for Family Caregivers of Patients with
> Cancer]. 榮總護理, 34(3), 220-226. https://doi.org/10.6142/vghn.34.3.220
> Azzam, P., Mroueh, M., Francis, M., Daher, A. A., & Zeidan, Y. H.
> (2020). Radiation-induced neuropathies in head and neck cancer:
> prevention and treatment modalities. Ecancermedicalscience, 14, 1133.
> https://doi.org/10.3332/ecancer.2020.1133

Example of match (orange):

[image]

The regex works, except it's almost matching the space before `[` when where is a title between square brackets (the English translation of the Chinese title).

How to modify the regex so it doesn't match that space?

I tried adding a negative lookahead, but nothing changed.

```
(^.*[ ]\(\d{4}\)\.[ ])([^[.]+|(?![ ] \[))(.*)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kUW4Ug/1)

Comment: Maybe something like `^(.*? \(\d{4}\)\.) ([^[.]*[^[.\s]+)\s*(.*)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hey, that worked great. Maybe post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*? \(\d{4}\)\.) ([^[.]*[^[.\s]+)\s*(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HtwInX/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*? \(\d{4}\)\.)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, then a space, `(`, four digits, `)` and a dot
- - a space
- `([^[.]*[^[.\s]+)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `[` and `.`, and then a char other than `[`, `.` and whitespace (this trims the space on the right)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.